# Clase heredada de QTabWidget genera error

Tags: python, pyqt

Tengo este codigo:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTabWidget, QSizePolicy, QWidget, QLabel, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFont, QFontDatabase
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSignal

class A(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


class B (QMainWindow, A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(B.__mro__)
        self.addTab(QLabel(),"tab1")
        self.tabBar()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    a = B()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Me esta generando este error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "C:\Users\cespitia\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2023.3\scratches\prove.py", line 25, in 
a = B()
^^^
File "C:\Users\cespitia\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2023.3\scratches\prove.py", line 20, in **init**
self.addTab(QLabel(),"tab1")
^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'addTab'

si cambio el orden mro, se soluciona el problema pero si quiero que la calse principal sea QMainwindow por ejemplo porque me generaría un error de no encontrar el parámetro, si esta heredando de la clase a que contiene el widget, lo mismo para este ejemplo.

```
class B (QMainWindow, QTabWidget):

    def __init__(self):

     super().__init__()
    
        print(B.__mro__)
    
        self.addTab(QLabel(),"tab1")
    
        self.tabBar()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    a = B()
    sys.exit(app.exec()
```

Comment: Me gustaría saber cual es la explicación de este error, es debido a que no es logico tener un mainWindow y un tabWindow en una misma clase?, o a que se debe el error

Comment: Te recomiendo no hacer herencia multiple de objetos de cualquier binding de qt. No se las implicaciones internas, pero se que se debe a que esos objetos son bindings de c++ y que puede dar resultados impredecibles. Mirá esta pregunta del sitio en inglés https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73254567/pyqt5-qgraphicsitem-multiple-inheritance

Answer (score 1):

Primero de todo, **la herencia múltiple de `QObject`s no está soportada en Qt**.

Además de eso tenemos que tener en cuenta que Qt está implementada en C++, PyQT y PySide son por tanto bindings a librerías en C++, creados con la ayuda de generadores de binding propios (SIP y Shiboken respectivamente).

C++ y Python manejan la herencia múltiple de forma muy distinta y la cosa se complica aún más cuando entra en juego `super()` y la herencia múltiple cooperativa de Python, en cuyo caso todas las clases implicadas deben usar `super` correctamente y estar implementadas para permitir la cooperación entre si. De hecho en Pyside2 había hasta hace poco un bug por el cual `QObject` no llamaba a los inicializares del resto de clases apropiadamente, rompiendo la cadena de herencia y la cooperación por completo.

Por lo tanto, el comportamiento de la herencia múltiple cuando se usa con clases de Qt no solo depende de Python, sino de los objectos en C++ que hay por debajo envueltos por los objetos Python. Esto puede desencadenar en resultados inesperados si el propio binding no maneja la situación de forma adecuada y está explícitamente soportado por el mismo.

La herencia múltiple ya de por si es compleja, hasta el punto que muchos defienden evitarla de ser posible, eso sin meter de por medio la interacción de dos lenguajes con un manejo distinto de la misma. En la gran mayoría de casos simplemente usar otro enfoque, como composición, señales, etc permite resolver el mismo problema de forma menos propensa a errores o comportamientos no deseados y mejorando el mantenimiento del código.

Si aún se desea usar herencia múltiple en PyQt, tener en cuenta lo siguiente:

- No se debe heredar de dos `QObject` (cualquier clase que derive del mismo).
- Si puedes heredar de QObject junto a clases no-QObject.
- La primera clase al heredar debe ser el QObject.

La propia [documentación de PyQt5](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/gotchas.html#multiple-inheritance) especifica lo siguiente (traducción libre):

> No es posible definir una nueva clase de Python que derive de más de
> una clase de Qt. La excepción son las clases específicamente pensadas
> para actuar como mixins, como es el caso de las clases que implementan
> interfaces en Qt (por ejemplo, `QQmlParserStatus`).